# The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: laravel, wamp64

I am new to Laravel. I want to composer install the code but I get the error. Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
 Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser ^7.0 -> satisfiable by php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser[7.0.0].
    - php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser 7.0.0 requires ext-mailparse * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mailparse extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - D:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

The mailparse extension does not yet support PHP 7.3 or 7.4.

You need change your PHP version

https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-mailparse-extension/

Install Mailparse on PHP 7.0, 7.1, or 7.2
To install this extension on PHP 7.X, SSH in to your server as root and run the following commands:

```sh
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo pecl7.X-sp install --nodeps mailparse
sudo bash -c "echo extension=mailparse.so > /etc/php7.X-sp/conf.d/mailparse.ini"
sudo service php7.X-fpm-sp restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I has try use the lower version php but it still get the same error. Can I have the installation command step for Window?

Comment: You are using WAMPServer, go to the Sourceforge page or for a simpler view go to the [backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and pick a version of PHP, download the ADDON and install it